# Using GWT Multipage

Tags: gwt

I am using [GWT Multipage](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-multipage/) in my project right now. This framework made my gwt application multi-page with ease. However, there is some problem I have right now.

I've been trying to figure out one problem that Entrypoint gets exposed when something unknown is passed in the web app like:

http://gwtmultipage.appspot.com/Two.html?query

or like this:

http://gwtmultipage.appspot.com/Two.html#query

All the EntryPoints are shown / exposed.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: BTW, the web link above is live. So you can check what I mean by clicking those links.