# How to achieve GWT multipage

Tags: gwt

How to achieve multipage with GWT, such that the gwt application can have multiple `EntryPoint` that is mapped to a html.

Like `HomeEntryPoint` mapped to `home.html` and 
`EditEntryPoint` mapped to `edit.html` and so on. Such that to load the EntryPoint it is access through the URL like this: `http://localhost:8080/home.html` or `http://localhost:8080/edit.html`

Right now I am using [GWT Multipage](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-multipage/) however I think its not maintained anymore. And it has some issues that I can't fix right now.

Issue like [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434950/using-gwt-multipage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this will mean that your app will have to start back up again when the next page loads - if you are okay with this, then...

There are a few ways of doing something like this. The quickest/easiest is going to be to list all of your entrypoints in the module file, and at the top of each `onModuleLoad` do a check if it is at the right page. Something like (customized for each page/entrypoint of course):

```
 if (!Window.Location.getPath().toLowerCase().endsWith("myhtmlpage.html") {
   return;
 }
```

GWT will compile all the entry points (and all depending classes, to just make one set of files, each class downloaded only once) into one js file, and all entrypoints will run, but they will stop themselves if they shouldn't be run at that time.

A step further would be to change this to use an annotation on each entrypoint, and a generator for all entrypoints (Did you know your entrypoint instance is created with GWT.create? It's true!), which would override `onModuleLoad` and add this logic automatically.

Edited to use getPath() in place of getHref(), and to toLowerCase() that string to ensure that no case issues crop up

Comment: Clever solution with getHref(), so I will just put the entrypoint class entry with the module.gwt.xml file in my code?

Comment: wait, btw, since the check is with endsWith("something.html"), this will have problems with fragment identifiers and URL parameters, am I correct?

Comment: Great point, sorry that I missed that... Correcting it now to use window.location.pathname (Location.getPath() in gwt)

Comment: I tried this approach but, the application throws an error for accessing other than the main html "app.html". Like user.html causes "RequestURI=/user.html"

Answer (score 0):

How about simply making them separate applications, compiled separately?

Comment: Yes, that is definitely the final solution, but right now for my prototype, I just need to make everything in one place.

Comment: How is using separate modules incompatible with having "everything in one place"? Simply pass several module names to the DevMode or Compiler instead of just one; and the Google Plugin for Eclipse makes this really easy, if that's what you use.

Comment: To one advantage to only one module is that the user only has to wait for one large download, especially if there is some overlap in the different pieces of the application - using just the Widget class and its dependencies causes a download of about 45k, and of course larger classes mean more js to pull down.

Comment: But then what's the advantage of using several HTML host pages?